# A respectful alternative to the word "you" or "your"

Tags: formality

I want to know a respectful and formal alternative for the word *you* or *your* . In my native language there are respectful words for *you*. But in English *you* doesn't seem to be respectful for calling elder people such as teachers or seniors.

*Is there any alternatives. Forgive me if this has been asked before...*

Comment: Using _you_ is in no way disrespectful in English. We show respect in other ways (by not using informal language; by making requests indirectly, for example "Would you mind doing this?" or "Could you please do this?" rather than "Will you do this?"; by using Mr/Mrs/Professor X rather than the person's given name).

Comment: Your title should start 'A respectful', since 'respectful' starts with a consonant.

Comment: Historically, "you" was the more respectful form and "thee/thou" was informal/familiar. English has changed to the point were the more formal "you" is used in all cases, but it's still perfectly appropriate for formal situations.